# LINQ to Object Join operator and equality

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following simple LINQ to Object query:

```
var accountsWithOpportunities = (from a in accountGetServices
                                 join o in opportunities on a equals o.Account
                                 select a).ToList();
```

This query always 0 results but this query does not:

```
var accountsWithOpportunities = (from a in accountGetServices
                                 join o in opportunities on a.Id equals o.Account.Id
                                 select a).ToList();
```

Therefor, I reached to the conclusion that my equality operation is doing something wrong.
I have the following abstract class that is being used for all models:

```
public abstract class BaseModel<T> : BaseModel
        where T : class, IIdentifyable
    {
        public static bool operator ==(BaseModel<T> c1, BaseModel<T> c2)
        {
            T t1 = c1 as T;
            T t2 = c2 as T;

            if (object.ReferenceEquals(t1, t2)) return true;
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(t1, null)) return false;
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(t2, null)) return false;

            return c1.Equals(c2);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(BaseModel<T> c1, BaseModel<T> c2)
        {
            return !(c1 == c2);
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseModel : IEquatable<BaseModel>
    {
        public bool Equals(BaseModel other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            var identifyable1 = this as IIdentifyable;
            var identifyable2 = other as IIdentifyable;

            return identifyable1.Id == identifyable2.Id;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj) && Equals(obj as BaseModel);
        }
    }
```

I placed breakpoints on each function to see what goes on under the hood but none of them are hit.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  return base.Equals(obj) && Equals(obj as BaseModel);
}
```

This part seems to be wrong. `base.Equals` calls `object.ReferenceEquals` which always (or at least in most of the cases) returns false and therefore the other expression is never evaluated.

**EDIT**

Also, as you pointed out earlier, GetHashCode gets called (you should get a compiler warning that you've overridden Equals but not GetHashCode). So change the GetHashCode to return the Id of the entity and it should start working.

Comment: The Equals function is never called anyway. None of them are for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is `public override bool Equals(object obj)` not being hit? I see you are calling `object.Equals` here which would make it always return `false`. A better implementation would be:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return this.Equals(obj as BaseModel);
}
```

Comment: Replaced it with your implementation. The function is not being hit!

Comment: The GetHashCode function is being hit though. However it is not implemented since I don't have any property in this model.

Comment: @the_drow weird. What is the type of `accountGetServices`. It must be an `IEnumerable<BaseModel>` to get it to hit the right `Equals` method.

Comment: It's IEnumerable<Account>. Account inherits from BaseModel<T>

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to override `GetHashCode()` to always return 0.
Then all the equality functions are being hit.
I'm not sure why or if there's a better way to implement `GetHashCode()`.